# Ajax Pagination

Tags: css, jquery

I am going to write an Ajax pagination code by myself using jQuery and css . Can you suggest me an algorithm or steps to complete that code successfully.

Comment: I think you're confused about the meaning of "write by myself"

Comment: not like that i want to develop a ajax pajination in j2ee fram work.. i am going to write a ajax pagination code by myself as a learning as well implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it for one of my old project.

1. Create a html table and a set of "li"s with relevant page numbers ( you have to calculate the number of pages to display according to the number of rows matching to the search value in the database).
2. I wrote a function to send jquery ajax request with Search text value, result set start index and number of rows per page. Replace the existing search table data ( + pagination li set) with response data returned from the server.
3. Then bind above function to the click event of the set of "li"s I have mentioned in the first point. ( result set start index and number of rows depends on the clicked li element. )
4. In the server side, Query the database for selected result set range.
   SELECT * FROM my TABLE WHERE search_field = 'SEARCH_VALUE%' LIMIT START_INDEX_FOR_RESULT_SET , NUMBER_OF_ROWS_PER_PAGE

Create HTML structure of the search result table and navigation "li"s and send it as the response for the ajax request. See step 2 for what will happen to this generated html content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what web framework you're using, but Ryan Bates' of Railscasts did a screencast of doing exactly this with jQuery. It's episode 174, [Pagination with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax). Should give you a good starting point.